# Using the find command on the ftp server

Tags: ftp

I am logged in to an ftp server and want to find a particular directory within all the directories that exist there. I am looking for a command similar to the Unix find command.
Is there something like this available?

Comment: I don't think that's off-topic here as I asked myself that question in a professional setting. (Developers of software I use at work have changed the directory layout of their ftp server and I can't find some specific source code there anymore.) Plus, I'd have an answer not yet mentioned here: Many ftp servers have ls-lr.txt.gz files with indices of the server's contents. Downloading that one and grepping through is similar to the Unix command locate which again is similar to find, just with cached contents.

Answer (score 7):

There's `lftp` too. You can perform things like :

```
lftp user@ftp.domain.net:/> find . | grep WORD
```

Answer (score 3):

While theoretically possible I'm not aware of any ftp-client to support this.

**EDIT:** As idursun pointed out Total Commander can do it.

It's not possible with regular `ftp`, but if you have a shell account you can login with `ssh` or `putty` and use `find.`

If you really have only ftp-access you could try to list all directories recursively to a file and then `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Total Commander can do that. Connect to ftp using the built-in ftp client and perform a normal search (Alt+F7) in the ftp tab.

Answer (score 0):

Some FTPd have a file database that can be queried:

```
user@ftp.domain.net:/> site search foo
/pub/beer/foo/
/pub/beer/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are ways to do this way client side, for example by getting a directory listing, and looping through those directory to get a list; theres no way to do this server side without altering the ftpd code. You arent in a shell server side, you certainly arent spawning a shell server side, so you cant use any commands server side that arent provided by the ftp server, as other answers show.

Answer (score -1):

Mount the ftp folder locally using curlftpfs.